# Regex for Case insensitve .net and Javascript

Tags: regex

I have a following Regex , which is used in many places (both clientside validation and serverside validation)

**Client Side**

```
var _timeFormat = "^(1|01|2|02|3|03|4|04|5|05|6|06|7|07|8|08|9|09|10|11|12{1,2}):(([0-5]{1}[0-9]{1}\s{0,1})( [AM|PM]{2,2}))\W{0}$";
```

**server side**

```
public const string TIME = @"^(?-i:1|01|2|02|3|03|4|04|5|05|6|06|7|07|8|08|9|09|10|11|12{1,2}):(([0-5]{1}[0-9]{1}\s{0,1})([AM|PM]{2,2}))\W{0}$";
```

My problem is when the user types am or Am/ pm or Pm it should accept.

I have tried

```
   var _timeFormat = "^(?-i:1|01|2|02|3|03|4|04|5|05|6|06|7|07|8|08|9|09|10|11|12{1,2}):(([0-5]{1}[0-9]{1}\s{0,1})( [AM|PM]{2,2}))\W{0}$";
```

it works in serverside but on javascript it doesn't work.

please suggest what should i use.

I don't want to use

```
 var re = new RegExp(_timeFormat, 'i');
```

because i am using that in many places and cannot change in all places.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would change it one time in a central place to avoid multiple changes in the future

Comment: just curious, why `12{1,2}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simplified your regex a bit. It will work both client and server-side.

```
^(0?[1-9]|1[0-2]):([0-5]\d)\s?([aApP][mM])$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/weJXis8b6FNlxxkl)

Version without groups (if you don't use them and check only validity of input value):

```
^(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5]\d\s?[aApP][mM]$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/zftZeEx1LjBBw_qu)

Comment: +1 For this exact problem, this is probably the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

Since the RegExp constructor [returns a copy of a passed in RegExp if passed one](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10.4.1), you could just make _timeFormat into a case insensitive RegExp and have it propagate;

```
var _timeFormat = /^(1|01|2|02|3|03|4|04|5|05|6|06|7|07|8|08|9|09|10|11|12{1,2}):(([0-5]{1}[0-9]{1}\s{0,1})( [AM|PM]{2,2}))\W{0}$/i;

var re = new RegExp(_timeFormat);  // re is now also case insensitive
```

Answer (score 1):

One reason your client side regex is failing is because you have not escaped the `\` in your string.

You need to either escape the backslash with a double backslash:

```
"\\s"
```

or use a regex literal:

```
/\s/
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

var _timeFormat = /^(1|01|2|02|3|03|4|04|5|05|6|06|7|07|8|08|9|09|10|11|12{1,2}):(([0-5]{1}[0-9]{1}\s{0,1})(am|pm))\W{0}$/i;

alert(_timeFormat.test("01:10AM"));